# Issues looping through graphql response in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am having issues looping through this data. This data is a the response from a graphql webrequest. I would like to loop through this data and execute another webrequest for each ID. I am not able to get powershell to read the nested objects.

```
{
    "data": {
        "Messages": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": "ca96b6e3-b138-46c2-92da-b13d1b2bc03c"
                },
                {
                    "id": "05035088-e681-47d1-905d-787c0967897e"
                },
                {
                    "id": "8c48af4f-326d-47e5-9714-590521cc3be8"
                },
                {
                    "id": "44cf1adc-e451-4140-9fd9-aa3a947f7e2a"
                },
                {
                    "id": "d7859528-5385-4e62-b234-a4a7978fe6a3"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b62ef4aa-29bf-4f03-9b0b-de8042b68020"
                },
                {
                    "id": "ee6e3b25-3f15-4807-9a46-3f9de4867aa5"
                },
                {
                    "id": "aed8a312-eac9-4053-abb7-bd93f07dab7a"
                },
                {
                    "id": "69421eb8-6c7a-4d80-ba24-c08ca16872c7"
                },
                {
                    "id": "9a4ffa1c-0176-420a-9257-5ebfca44b0e4"
                },
                {
                    "id": "645777ba-f29d-41c1-b750-939726712f42"
                },
                {
                    "id": "702eabb8-50dc-4808-babd-f0317a9cad94"
                },
                {
                    "id": "a8b9b755-5fbd-4ab6-8f22-6be1b4c3cc65"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e56c473f-4044-4678-9e0c-0e92f04126ad"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b3e6c14e-b7fb-451f-afc8-b7f22b1815df"
                },
                {
                    "id": "30f4f9be-32cb-4bdd-878f-fa4ff55c89fb"
                },
                {
                    "id": "08293318-5e9b-4fa0-919e-6e0611d4f89c"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5ea6b3bc-19a5-43d5-ab25-b01770676d49"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7f01e29f-6fe6-4b06-a5d5-e3e46f2f74da"
                },
                {
                    "id": "59462e10-429e-4878-9cc7-424882e016de"
                },
                {
                    "id": "20f3aaa7-a276-4339-bf37-4fe9ff9b2dcf"
                },
                {
                    "id": "65a05042-e2de-48b4-80dc-2dfff9ce4c6b"
                },
                {
                    "id": "f859f606-e3e6-4d66-8a44-e938b78c08a2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "45ce080e-83ca-4a30-84d3-e5e01f3f361a"
                },
                {
                    "id": "f8397dc3-027a-4db8-bc6a-e57c219ea836"
                },
                {
                    "id": "712cc2e6-270c-4728-a546-6bf43b072a18"
                },
                {
                    "id": "551e78cc-db91-491b-8c48-9d9ec2fc8322"
                },
                {
                    "id": "eb47d873-bfc7-4d74-ad5a-9f39a2a9cf31"
                },
                {
                    "id": "50cc9637-4384-4e47-925d-302b07bb0158"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5147ef32-c7e4-443f-97e1-53f3321616c1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `ConvertFrom-Json` but this is all that is see.

```
data               
----               
@{Messages=}
```

Comment: It may look funny but it still works, like `$json.data.messages.nodes.id` returns the id object array.

Comment: Still having issues. ConvertFrom-JSON sets $json to @{data=}

Comment: This is a display formatting issue - your ```node``` data is *there*, but the console shows it in a truncated format when it gets converted to display output. Try this, for example: ```$json = ...; $data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json; $data.data.Messages.nodes``` and you'll see the nodes ids being displayed in a table instead.

Comment: $data

data
----
@{Messages=}

Comment: Yep, that’s how it converts in-memory pscustomobjects to a string to display *on-screen*. If you drill down the object hierarchy you’ll find the data you’re after. Try ```$data.data.Messages.nodes``` and you’ll see a table of ids…

Comment: Or if you’re still sceptical, ```$json = …; $data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json``` and then ```$data | ConvertTo-Json``` to see the entire pscustomobject converted back to json…